# How to prevent backspace from coming out extra "r" letter

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

Currently, I'm working on an input box where the input box is to input a Reddit link.

My input box is coded such that when the user types a character, there will be a default `r/` in front, followed by the user input.

However, now the issue I'm facing is whenever the user backspace when the input box is left with `r/`, an extra `r` will appear after `r/` whenever the user hits backspace. e.g. `r/r`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
case getType(ViewerAction.changeInputSubredditAddNewSource): {
            const s = action.payload.inputSubredditAddNewSource.split('/').slice(1).join('');

            if (action.payload.inputSubredditAddNewSource.indexOf('r/') === 0) {            
                return state.set('inputSubredditAddNewSource', `r/${s}`);
            }         
                const st = action.payload.inputSubredditAddNewSource;
                return state.set('inputSubredditAddNewSource', `r/${st}`);
        }
```

Comment: What you could do is replacing leading `r/` with an empty string whenever the user enters something. That way you can turn the problem around and always add `r/` in the handling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be handled in your component, not redux. Your input should detect when the backspace button is clicked and if the field is empty (just 'r/') - do not update the field's value.

You can simply add if statement in your input's onChange handler when the new input's `value.length` is less than 2 (1st char: 'r', 2nd char: '/') - do not update the value - otherwise, update.